# How to order data by most recent date, THEN by distinct ID

Tags: mysql

I have this data in a mysql table:

```
ID_Registro  Tiempo              Tipo ID_Guardia ID_Estacion
+---------+---------------------+----+---------+------+
| 18      | 2018-07-15 12:00:00 | 2  |    3    | 7    |
| 17      | 2018-07-15 12:00:00 | 2  |    3    | 7    |
|  7      | 2018-07-15 11:00:00 | 1  |    4    | 7    |
|  6      | 2018-07-15 10:00:00 | 1  |    3    | 7    |
+---------+---------------------+----+---------+------+
```

I'm getting this data with this query:

```
    SELECT ID_Registro,
       Tiempo,
       Tipo,
       ID_Guardia,
       ID_Estacion
FROM registro_guardias 
WHERE ID_Estacion = 7 
ORDER BY Tiempo DESC, ID_Registro DESC
```

What I NEED to get is the most recent registry (on the date time field Tiempo, and I'm also ordering it by the ID) BUT with each different Guards (ID_Guardia)

Meaning this:

```
ID_Registro  Tiempo             Tipo ID_Guardia ID_Estacion
+---------+---------------------+----+---------+------+
| 18      | 2018-07-15 12:00:00 | 2  |    3    | 7    |
|  7      | 2018-07-15 11:00:00 | 1  |    4    | 7    |
+---------+---------------------+----+---------+------+
```

Which are all the different ID_Guardia on that station (ID_Estacion).

---

So far I've attempted to place a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT ID_Registro,
       Tiempo,
       Tipo,
       ID_Guardia,
       ID_Estacion
FROM registro_guardias 
WHERE ID_Estacion = 7 
GROUP BY ID_Guardia
ORDER BY Tiempo DESC, ID_Registro DESC
```

Getting:

```
    ID_Registro  Tiempo              Tipo  ID_Guardia ID_Estacion
    +---------+---------------------+----+---------+------+
    |  7      | 2018-07-15 11:00:00 | 1  |    4    | 7    |
    |  6      | 2018-07-15 10:00:00 | 1  |    3    | 7    |
    +---------+---------------------+----+---------+------+
```

Placing a DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID_Guardia,
       ID_Registro,
       Tiempo,
       Tipo,
       ID_Estacion
FROM registro_guardias rg
WHERE ID_Estacion = 7 
ORDER BY Tiempo DESC, ID_Registro DESC


ID_Guardia  ID_Registro  Tiempo              Tipo ID_Estacion
+----------+-----------+---------------------+---+---+
| 3        | 18        | 2018-07-15 12:00:00 | 2 | 7 |
| 3        | 17        | 2018-07-15 12:00:00 | 2 | 7 |
| 4        |  7        | 2018-07-15 11:00:00 | 1 | 7 |
| 3        |  6        | 2018-07-15 10:00:00 | 1 | 7 |
+----------+-----------+---------------------+---+---+
```

I'm maybe thinking wrong but, how can I get the results I need?

UPDATE:

I've tried it this way, but I still don't get the Primary ID I also need on the query.

```
  SELECT ID_Registro,
       MAX(Tiempo),
       Tipo,
       ID_Estacion
       ID_Guardia,
FROM registro_guardias 
WHERE ID_Estacion = 7
GROUP BY ID_Guardia
ORDER BY Tiempo ASC
```

I get this, the ID's DONT match the highest (Tiempo) Time registry. They only match the first occurrence.

```
+---+---------------------+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2018-07-15 13:00:00 | 2 | 7 | 3 |
| 2 | 2018-07-15 13:00:00 | 2 | 7 | 4 |
| 7 | 2018-07-15 11:00:00 | 2 | 7 | 5 |
| 8 | 2018-07-15 13:00:00 | 2 | 7 | 6 |
+---+---------------------+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Did my answer help or do you need something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to group by `ID_Guardia` and select the row with the maximum `Tiempo` value. That would be greatest-n-per-group, so one of the possible solutions is something like this:

```
SELECT r1.ID_Registro,
   r1.Tiempo,
   r1.Tipo,
   r1.ID_Guardia,
   r1.ID_Estacion
FROM registro_guardias r1 LEFT JOIN registro_guardias r2
  ON (r1.ID_Guardia = r2.ID_Guardia AND r1.Tiempo < r2.Tiempo)
WHERE r2.Tiempo IS NULL AND ID_Estaction = 7;
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group for other solutions.

Comment: It does some of what I need but it gets me all the results of the station, I need the registries sorted by the station guards independently:

Which would be:

GROUP BY rg.ID_Guardia
ORDER BY rg.ID_Registro DESC

but when I do that mysql IGNORES the order by and brings me a random ID_Registro. (For example I have an ID with the number 11 that is more recent but the query brings me the ID = 9, 9 has the same datetime as reg 11. I need it to bring me the highest and the lastest, grouped by the guards.

Comment: @Carlos Your edited code can't work. You can't group by some column and select other columns without specifying an aggregate function.

Comment: @Carlos Please provide a prepared schema online and share it here (e. g. sqlfiddle.com/).